# Choose an output audio device different from the default on WMP 11

Tags: windows, windows-media-player, audio-output

I like to play my music through a Hi-Fi audio equipment and everything else (like windows sounds, web videos and such) through my default PC speakers.

On WIndows XP I had WMP 9 and I could do that with no problems since I can choose what audio device (which sound card) to use, and that selection is for WMP only, which can be different from Windows' default audio device.

But now that I have Windows Vista and WMP 11 I cannot longer choose an audio device just for WMP, or at least I can't find a way to do it (the control in the options dialog is no longer there).

Was this useful feature really removed from WMP 11? or there is some other way to do it?

Comment: can you mention your audio(sound) card ?

Comment: is there a command line to change this between specific devices? the application being to assign said command to a hotkey to switch wmp to specific devices... I found a shortcut that will change the system's default device http://www.raymond.cc/blog/download/?did=826 But it would be neat if I can do it specifically for wmp and leave the default as it is... let us know if your savy enough..

Answer (score 12):

In Windows Media Player 11 and 12, click Tools > Options > Devices > Speakers > Properties > Select the audio device.

You may also have to restart WMP for changes to take effect.

<sub>The following screenshot shows where the option is in Windows Media Player 12, Windows 7.</sub>

[[image: Screenshot (WMP 12, Win7)]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Yjtr.png)

Comment: The drop-down list to select a device is not there. I just see the "Advance options..." button.

Comment: William describes Windows 7, in Vista there is no drop-down, but clicking the 'Advanced...' button allows you to choose the device to be used by WMP. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: In Vista the "Advanced..." button takes you to the Windows sound device control panel where you can only choose the default sound device for the whole system.

Comment: Worked for me, though remember to play a different file than the current one, after saving the settings so the changes can take effect, enjoy :)